# GIT clone android project does not show files correct

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I create a new Android project on Android studios. Using VCS & Git I created my first commit and pushed it up to Bitbucket. That part was easy.

Now that I got to my other PC I wanted to pull the repo down and continue working as normal. However the Java files and XML files is full of error and it look like the project did not initialize correctly or files/libraries where missing. Even folders are in the incorrect places.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can force a refresh of Gradle and cache file by doing the following.

- Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files
- File > Invalidate Cache/Restart... > Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps

1. Clone from git or your desire version control
2. Delete .idea file if it's there
3. Now import your project and sync

If still didn't work comment below to guide you more.